# Bundle local NPM dependencies and publish

Tags: npm

I have a project comprised of:

- module1/
- module2/ (depends on module1)
- mainmodule/ (depends on module2)

Is is possible to publish mainmodule without publishing module1 and module2?
I.e. to somehow bundle the local dependencies inside of mainmodule?

Answer (score 3):

Are you importing the dependency module using `import` or `require`? If yes, yes you can create a unique bundle from your `mainmodule` using a bundler like webpack.
Inside your mainmodule, you just need a package.json file and Webpack installed locally or globally. After that just run this command

```
webpack mainmodule.js -o bundle.js
```

and Webpack will bundle all the modules together is just one module.